# Issue with parameters assignment in ADODB Command

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vbscript, sql-server-2000, adodb

We use an ADODB command to perform queries (call stored procedures) on our SQL Server 2000 database, using SQLOLEDB driver.

On one of our server we have issues when we assign parameter values. Here's how it goes :

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.CommandTimeout = 0
conn.ConnectionTimeout = 15
conn.Mode = 1 ' adModeRead
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString ' SQLOLEDB
conn.CursorLocation = 3 ' adUseClient
conn.Open

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn ' previously created connection
cmd.CommandType = 4 ' adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.StoredProcedureName"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
cmd.Parameters.Refresh ' Get the parameters info from the database

' Pseudo code here :
Foreach cmd.parameters
 cmd.parameters(index).value = somevalue
Next
```

This code actually works on our production server, but for some odd reasons it does not work on our dev server and generates this error : **Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation** when we assign a value (which contain a decimal part, let's say a string like "12.75") to a datatype money parameter.

The code is exactly the same on dev and on prod. Do this could have something to do with regional settings, language of ADODB, language of thr OS or some other Windows component ? Because it is classic ASP code we already looked at Session.LCID but they are the same on both servers, so we are clueless right now.

Have any idea ?

Comment: Often this error is due to a length problem.  I suggest you double- check the length being used when the parameters are being created.

Comment: Length is not the problem, it's a money field, and it works ok on an other server, with the same values passed.

Comment: If it's consistently working on one server and not another then there is likely to be something distinct and ancillary to the ADODB transaction on the failing server. Given this fact, in conjunction with the Classic ASP transaction pipeline, it's going to be VERY unlikely that we're dealing with a code problem...ASP or SQL StoredProc.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible the dev server is set up with a different base language or other regional settings? Just for kicks try assigning the value 12,75 instead of 12.75.

Comment: You are right, when I change dots for commas, it works great, but I'm pretty sure it will fail on production web server.

Comment: Not if you change the settings so that both are the same!

Answer (score 1):

From the MS KB

> Parameters.refresh will fail in some situations or return
>   information that is not entirely correct. Parameters.refresh is
>   particularly vulnerable when used on ASP pages.

There is a known issue regarding parameter direction when using Parameters.refresh from Classic ASP. MS guidance is to manually generate the parameters.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183008
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174223

Comment: We cannot afford to change that behaviour, the whole app uses that for calls to Stored Procedures. And I also would like to know better what are the situations which makes Parameters.Refresh to work incorrectly ? Also Parameters.Refresh it does not seem to be the issue since parameters are actually refreshed, varchar values are assigned ok everywhere and stored proc not containing money or float values works fine. (and everything else on an other server)

Comment: Which MDAC are you using? Which version of IIS? Conceptually, I think understand what you're doing and why you're doing it as well as your reasoning behind saying that you cannot afford to change it. My first suggestion is to make absolutely sure that the environments between servers are exactly identical...that means MDAC level [even to ensuring that the versions of the SQLOLEDB driver are the same]. You hinted that there might be some disparity between hosting environments relative to language, regional settings, etc...Can you provide any details regarding the scope of those differences?

Comment: Also, what's your architecture? Is this a n-Tier application with multiple web servers hitting a common SQL server or are we talking about distinct application instances as well as distinct SQL Server instances?

Comment: There's no special architecture, ASP pages on web server A (dev) connect directly to SQL Server 2000 on server B. Web server C connect to the same SQL Server instance. We will look into versions of MDAC, IIS and Regional Settings and languages of the server and users if that can help. I'll keep you informed.